# Using a junction table with RestKit to map relationships in Core Data

Tags: json, core-data, restkit

I have three different pairs of objects connected with a Many-To-Many relationship. One of these is
Product <<--->> Discount

Product contains some general data like a product category, name and identifier. Discounts link to Products and have price data and Dates marking the time frame the discounts are valid, among other things.

I have successfully used RKEntityMappings and RKResponseDescriptors to fetch these objects from a REST API (implemented with Node.js) and these all work fine.

My problem is that we have a third API endpoint that returns the relationships between these objects (Product and Discount) in an array, like this:

```
[
    {"discountid":1,"productid":3},
    {"discountid":1,"productid":2},
    {"discountid":108,"productid":29}
]
```

I know that I could make an object in the middle and then map that as an entity to the aforementioned JSON output, however as I do not have any other data to store in that I'd prefer not to.

If I skipped Core Data and used sqlite I could just make my own junction table, but after reading numerous posts advising against it and searching for hours and hours I'm asking: is there a way I can use this junction table output to map the relationships of two objects in Core Data using RestKit?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it without an intermediate object. Arguably you should be embedding this object, also as a list, into the original response...

Comment: @Wain Just as I feared. Thank you for your time.